# Data appears twice when goto previous fragment

Tags: android-layout, listview, android-fragments, textview, android

When i click back button from phone the previous fragment appears with data twice (like if we have an listview with name 'stack' and after coming back to previous fragment the listview appears twice with two times 'stack'). How can i resolve this twice data problem?